# Seeking Better (Symmetry Exploiting) Solution and Generalization of An Inequality

Tags: inequality, symmetry

Given positive variable $(x,y,a,b)$ where $x+y=1$, how does one "slickly" prove the following inequality? 
$$f(x,y) := \frac{xa+yb}{\sqrt{xa^2+yb^2}}\ge \frac{2\sqrt{ab}}{a+b}.$$
or simply
$$f(x,y) := \frac{xa+yb}{\sqrt{xa^2+yb^2}}\ge 2\sqrt{ab},$$
with constraint $a+b=1$.

I can prove this by differentiating $f(x,1-x)$ with respect to $x$ and show it first decrease then increase on $[0,1]$, or multiply both sides by the denominators then square them and examine the resulting quadratic equation. However, there is symmetry with this problem where the minimum of $f(x,y)$ is achieved at $xa=yb$. So I am seeking a more direct and "beautiful" approach to exploit this symmetry or use something like convexity, Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, etc, the methods I can use to generalize this problem.

Further, without knowing the minimum of $f(x,1-x)$ given $(a,b)$, how would one with a slick method and without the aforementioned differentiation, find the minimum?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In homogeneous form, the inequality can be written as
$$(xa+yb)^2(a+b)^2 \ge 4ab(x+y)(xa^2+yb^2)$$

which is the same as $(a-b)^2(ax-by)^2 \ge 0$, from which the inequality and equality conditions are both obvious.

Comment: Excellent! I understand the multiplication of  $x+y$. Could you please explicate how you find the factorization aside from brute force? Did you try $a=b$ and $ax=by$ then count the powers? Also, if I have not told you the lower bound of $f$, would you have derived it? How?

Comment: Well, the factor $a-b$ is obvious, and we also have the result that if the expression is symmetric, then $(a-b)^2$ must be a factor.  The factor $ax-by$ is similar.  For me, the inequality looked like a combination of AM-GM and CS, so the SOS proofs of both suggested the factorisation.

Comment: What does SOS stand for? Would you mind answering my last two questions in my last comment?

Comment: SOS is sum of squares - if you don't know the technique you will need to google it.  I don't know what you mean by "**the** lower bound" for $f$ - there are many possible - for e.g. your $(f + RHS)/2$ is clearly a "better" lower bound.

Comment: Is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum-of-squares_optimization what you are referring to as sum of squares technique? What I was saying was I had told you the minimum of $f(x,y)$ and asked for a slick proof which you gave. How would you find the minimum without being told?

Comment: @Hans  What I am trying to say is that there is no "minimum" in the sense you mean it. Finding the minimum/ infimum of $f(x, y)$ as a constant, $f > \frac1{\sqrt2}$ may make sense.  However finding the minimum as another function $g(x, y)$ does not make much sense, as $(f+g)/2$ gives you a "tighter" minimum and you can keep repeating the process to get more functions.  Without the RHS, you do not have a well defined problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25805/discussion-between-hans-and-macavity).

Comment: I have put up the optimization version of this question http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1360463/64809, would you be so kind to examine it? Thank you, @Macavity.

Comment: I have edited my last paragraph per your last comment.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more about your statement "and we also have the result that if the expression is symmetric, then $(a−b)^2$ must be a factor"? By symmetry, I suppose you mean exchanging $a$ and $b$ does not affect the resulting expression. However, after exchanging $a$ and $b$ with $x$ and $y$ in their original place, the expression does not seem to remain the same. I have the same question for the factor $ax-by$. Could you please shed some light on this question? Than you, Macavity.