# More elegant optimization by Symmetry?

Tags: inequality, optimization

Let
$$f(x,y,a,b) := \frac{xa+yb}{\sqrt{xa^2+yb^2}},$$
where $x,y,a,b$ are all positive.
Define
$$g(a,b) = \min_{x+y=1,\,x,y\ge 0}f(x,y,a,b).$$
How would one solve for $g(a,b)$?

I have solved this by differentiating $f(x,1-x)$ with respect to $x$ and show it first decrease then increase on $[0,1]$. So $f$ achieves the minimum 
$$g(a,b)= \frac{2\sqrt{ab}}{a+b}$$
at $x=\frac{b}{a+b}$.
How does one use a "slicker" way and exploit perhaps the symmetry of the problem to find the minimum?

This problem is another version of [this inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1360306/64809). But I would like to find how to find $g(a,b)$ in an elegant and perhaps symmetric way without knowing it a priori.